# Showing Red Stripe across HTML Page Error

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML, and I put together a very simple page showing a bus schedule.  Very strangley, I see a ride stripe created across the upper part of my first table.  You can view it here:  zen-software.com/shuttle.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<TITLE>WBPC Shuttle Bus Schedule</TITLE>
<meta name="description" content="WBPC Shuttle Bus Schedule">
<meta name="author" content="Zen Software, LLC">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}
th
{
text-align:left;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">
<div id="wrapper">
<header class="main_header">

<H1>Shuttle Bus Schedule</H1>
<h3><em>Shuttle bus pick-up/drop-off to Bismarck Civic Center.  Times after initial pick-up may vary slightly.</em></h3> 
<nav>
 <ul>
<li><a href="#Tue">Tuesday</a></li>
<li><a href="#Wed">Wednesday</a></li>
<li><a href="#Thu">Thursday</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>


<h2><a id="Tue">Tuesday Morning, May 20th</a></h2>
<h4>Buses will be running between listed hotels and the
Civic Center every half hour from 9:30 am until 9:00 pm</h4>
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Bus #1</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residence Inn</td>
  <td>9:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Country Suites</td>
  <td>9:40am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AmiericInn (front door Country Suites)</td>
  <td>9:40am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hampton Inn</td>
  <td>9:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Holiday Inn Express</td>
  <td>9:50am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sleep Inn (front door Holiday Inn Express)</td>
  <td>9:50am</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #2</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Suites (pick up behind hotel)</td>
  <td>9:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Inn (pick up behind Expressway Suites)</td>
  <td>9:30 am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ramkota Hotel (pick up at door #4)</td>
  <td>9:40 am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Radisson Hotel</td>
  <td>9:50 am</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #3</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Staybridge Suites</td>
  <td>9:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comfort Suites</td>
  <td>9:35am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comfort Inn (front of Comfort Suites)</td>
  <td>9:35am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mainstay Suites (front of Comfort Suites)</td>
  <td>9:35am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>America's Best Value (door B)</td>
  <td>9:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ramada Bismarck (door B of America's Best)</td>
  <td>9:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Days Inn (door B of America's Best)</td>
  <td>9:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Bus #4</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Seven Seas Hotel</td>
  <td>9:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>LaQuinta Inn</td>
  <td>9:50am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Kelly Inn</td>
  <td>9:55am</td> 
</tr>

</table>


<h2><a id="Wed">Wednesday Morning, May 21th</a></h2>
<h4>Buses will be running between listed hotels and the
Civic Center every half hour from 6:30 am until 9:30 pm</h4>
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Bus #1</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residence Inn</td>
  <td>6:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Country Suites</td>
  <td>6:40am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AmiericInn (front door Country Suites)</td>
  <td>6:40am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hampton Inn</td>
  <td>6:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Holiday Inn Express</td>
  <td>6:50 am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sleep Inn (front door Holiday Inn Express)</td>
  <td>6:50 am</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #2</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Suites (pick up behind hotel)</td>
  <td>6:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Inn (pick up behind Expressway Suites)</td>
  <td>6:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ramkota Hotel (pick up at Door #4)</td>
  <td>6:40am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Radisson Hotel</td>
  <td>6:50am</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #3</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Staybridge Suites</td>
  <td>6:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comfort Suites</td>
  <td>6:35am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comfort Inn (front of Comfort Suites)</td>
  <td>6:35am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mainstay Suites (front of Comfort Suites)</td>
  <td>6:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>America's Best Value (Door B)</td>
  <td>6:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ramada Bismarck (Door B of America's Best)</td>
  <td>6:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Days Inn (Door B of America's Best)</td>
  <td>6:45am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Bus #4</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Seven Seas Hotel</td>
  <td>6:30am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>LaQuinta Inn</td>
  <td>6:50am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Kelly Inn</td>
  <td>6:55am</td> 
</tr>

</table>


<h2>Wednesday Evening, May 21st</h2>
<h4>Buses will be running between listed hotels and the
Civic Center every half hour from 4:30 am until 7:30 pm</h4>
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Bus #1</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residence Inn, AmericInn, Country Suites, Hampton Inn, Holiday Inn Express, Sleep In</td>
  <td>4:30pm</td> 
</tr>


<tr>
  <th>Bus #2</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Suites, Expressway Inn, Ramkota Hotel, Radisson Hotel</td>
  <td>4:30pm</td> 
</tr>


<tr>
  <th>Bus #3</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Staybridge Suites, Comfort Inn, Comfort Suites, Mainstay Hotel, American's Best Value, Ramada Bismarck, Days Inn</td>
  <td>4:30pm</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #4</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Seven Seas Hotel, LaQuinta Inn, Kelly Inn</td>
  <td>9:30am</td> 
</tr>


</table>


<h2><a id="Thu">Thursday Morning, May 22th</a></h2>
<h4>Buses will be running between listed hotels and the
Civic Center every half hour from 7:00 am until 9:30 am</h4>
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Bus #1</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Residence Inn</td>
  <td>7:00am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Country Suites</td>
  <td>7:10am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AmiericInn (front door Country Suites)</td>
  <td>7:10am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hampton Inn</td>
  <td>7:15am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Holiday Inn Express</td>
  <td>7:20am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sleep Inn (front door Holiday Inn Express)</td>
  <td>7:20am</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #2</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Suites (Pick up behind hotel)</td>
  <td>7:00am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Expressway Inn (Pick up behind Expressway Suites)</td>
  <td>7:00am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ramkota Hotel (Pick up at Door #4)</td>
  <td>7:10am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Radisson Hotel</td>
  <td>7:20am</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Bus #3</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Staybridge Suites</td>
  <td>7:00am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comfort Suites</td>
  <td>7:05am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comfort Inn (front of Comfort Suites)</td>
  <td>7:05am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mainstay Suites (front of Comfort Suites)</td>
  <td>7:05am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>America's Best Value (Door B)</td>
  <td>7:15am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ramada Bismarck (Door B of America's Best)</td>
  <td>7:15am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Days Inn (Door B of America's Best)</td>
  <td>7:15am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Bus #4</th>
  <th>Initial pick-up</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Seven Seas Hotel</td>
  <td>7:00am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>LaQuinta Inn</td>
  <td>7:20am</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Kelly Inn</td>
  <td>7:25am</td> 
</tr>

</table>

 <footer>
<p>Taxi: 701-223-9000 or 701-667-4567.  Sponsored by: Bismarck-Mandan CVB</p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's part of the `background-image` you have on the `body`:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(images/bg4.jpg); /*THIS IMAGE*/
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Interesting..I had another style.css in my directly which was picking up the image, but in my dev environment I didn't see it.